# ARCore: Problems with the Object Manipulation Example Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I have some Problems with the Object Manipulation Example Scene, using Unity 2018.3.1 and ARCore 1.7.0.:
In general the Scene works, but I can only manipulate the last placed Object, no previously placed Objects. 
Apart from that, I cant translate/move Objects in the x/z area, only the height (y-Axis) can be changed. I cant find any reasons inside the scripts why those things don't work.
Did anyone else experience similar Problems or knows some solutions?